# Zoom to bounding box of path on externally loaded svg using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3 to load an external SVG map that isn't using topojson (as the map was hand created and non a traditional map). I'm trying to target the elements `#lines path` so that when clicked, each path zooms and fills its bounding box.

I'm trying to use [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom-to-bounding-box) from Mike Bostock but can't figure out how to replicate it with the data that isn't using topojson. See this line:

`.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)`

It this even possible?

Here is the code I'm using to load the SVG.

```js
var mapContainer = $('.map');

d3.xml("../assets/subwaymap.svg", function(error, subwayMap) {
  if (error) throw error;
  $('.map').append(subwayMap.documentElement)
```

I've tried getting the bounding box using `.getBBOX` but am confused at how it connects. It seems like all examples I've seen use `d3.create("svg")` and then tack all the functionality within that but since my data is already appended to the DOM, would this be necessary? Fairly new to D3. Thanks!

Comment: Try to add enough code (such as example svg) for us to replicate. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also could you not just select your appended svg with d3.select(‘svg’) and then follow the examples you mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two initial considerations: `d3.create("svg")` is rarely used in real D3 codes. Also, you don't have data appended to the DOM, just SVG elements you loaded (unless you're calling that *"data"*).

Back to your question, you don't need `path.bounds` to make your code work, actually you don't even need `d3.zoom`. All you need is get the element's box (with `getBBox`) and do the appropriate transform.

The real problem, though, is that you need to wrap all the elements in a `<g>`, because you cannot apply the transform to the root SVG in SVG 1.1 (apparently this is possible in SVG 2).

Here is a basic demo. In this demo I'm using an external SVG made with different elements (circle, rectangle, text...), which represents the SVG you're appending. You get this SVG with:

```
const svg = d3.select("svg");
```

Then, considering you somehow manage to fix the `<g>` problem I mentioned, you get that group...

```
const g = svg.select("g");
```

... and you select the elements you want to zoom in (here, everything), binding an event listener:

```
const elements = g.selectAll("*")
    .on("click", clicked);
```

In this demo I'm using Bostock's math, to save (my) time, but you can change it. Click the element to zoom in, click it again to zoom out.

```js
const width = 500,
  height = 400;
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const g = svg.select("g");
const elements = g.selectAll("*")
  .each(function() {
    d3.select(this).datum({})
  })
  .on("click", clicked);

function clicked(d) {
  d.clicked = !d.clicked;
  const bounds = this.getBBox();
  const x0 = bounds.x;
  const x1 = bounds.x + bounds.width;
  const y0 = bounds.y;
  const y1 = bounds.y + bounds.height;
  g.transition().duration(1000).attr("transform", d.clicked ? "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ") scale(" + (1 / Math.max((x1 - x0) / width, (y1 - y0) / height)) + ") translate(" + (-(x0 + x1) / 2) + "," + (-(y0 + y1) / 2) + ")" : "transform(0,0) scale(1)");
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="400">
<g>
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="teal"></circle>
<rect x="300" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:tomato;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"/>
<polygon points="200,100 250,190 160,210" style="fill:lavender;stroke:purple;stroke-width:3" />
<path d="M 140 350 q 150 -200 350 0" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
<text x="30" y="300" transform="rotate(-30, 30, 300)">Foo Bar Baz</text>
</g>
</svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All of this is very helpful and I learned a lot from looking up the things you suggested.